# Why compiler needs .java suffix but interpreter doesn't need .class suffix?

Tags: java

**To compile Foo.java:** javac Foo.java

**To run the program :** java Foo

Why compiler needs `.java` suffix but interpreter doesn't need `.class` suffix?

Comment: It's not a file name. Note that it's `javac pkg/Foo.java`, but `java pkg.Foo`. Applets do something mental as usual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a couple of other answers have explained, the Java compiler takes a file name as an argument, whereas the interpreter takes a class name. So you give the `.java` extension to the compiler because it's part of the file name, but you don't give it to the interpreter because it's not part of the class name.

But then, you might wonder, why didn't they just design the Java interpreter differently so that it would take a file name? The answer to that is that classes are not always loaded from `.class` files. Sometimes they come from JAR archives, sometimes they come [from the internet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html), sometimes they are constructed on the fly by a program, and so on. A class could come from any source that can provide the binary data needed [to define it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String%2C%20byte%5B%5D%2C%20int%2C%20int%29). Perhaps the same class could have different implementations from different sources, for example a program might try to load the most up-to-date version of some class from a URL, but would fall back to a local file if that failed. The designers of Java thought it best that when you're trying to run a program, you don't have to worry about having to track down the source that defines the class you're running. You just give the fully qualified class name and let Java (or rather, its `ClassLoader`s) do the hard work of finding it.

Answer (score 5):

The Java compiler takes a filename as input, hence Foo.java.

the Java interpreter takes the fully qualified class name and searches the classpath and current directory for the class. If you use java Foo.class it would search for the class named "class" in the package "Foo", and return NoClassDefFoundError if the class is in the default package, as I understand from your example

Answer (score 2):

Foo.java is the file name while simply "Foo" is the class name (not a file name). The default ClassLoader will search your current working directory for the file Foo.class and load it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to David Zaslavsky's explanation:

The java source code are not necessarily from `.java` files either. We can have a compiler that takes source code from difference character streams, as in the API `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`.

The cmd line util `javac` happens to be working with file sources only, so it desires file paths.

Comment: A fair point, but for purposes of explaining this particular design decision, you have to look back at Java 1.0 in which the `FileObject` abstraction didn't exist, and the only way to process source code was to put it in a file (or write your own compiler from scratch). In contrast, `ClassLoader`s have been around since the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Every language will have syntax and semantics which will establish rules and understanding between similar parties. Like how english has words, tenses, verbs etc., to simplfy communication between two english speaking parties. Java specification established syntax and semantics that compiler can understand only java files and interpreter can understand only .class files.