# Why do you remove .class when executing on the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Example: I have some source code, `FooBar.java`

```
javac FooBar.java
```

that gives me `FooBar.class`.

Why does the JVM command line API take `FooBar` instead of `FooBar.class` (working on UNIX FYI)?

Comment: dublicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651140/why-compiler-needs-java-suffix-but-interpreter-doesnt-need-class-suffix    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755746/why-javac-requires-java-extension-and-java-doesnt-require-class-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just a convention! Classes are loaded using their fully qualified class name. The `ClassLoader` then knows how to map class names to file names (e.g. by appending '.class').

Answer (score 4):

Just because you have to tell the JVM the name of the class you want to run, not its actual filename.
Another example, if your class was myPackage/FooBar.java you would compile to myPackage/FooBar.class, though you would put myPackage.FooBar as jvm argument.